# SQL query performance - same calculation in SELECT and WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, geospatial

I'm working with MySQL. Let's assume I have a table `test(id, x)` -- the data types are not important --and the following query

```
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE F(x) <= 1000;
```

Further, let's assume `F` is a "more or less complex" function. Now, what is the effect if I change the query to:

```
SELECT id, F(x)
FROM test
WHERE F(x) <= 1000;
```

That is, I need the result of F(x) not only for the WHERE condition but also as output in the SELECT clause. Can I safely assume that MySQL is clever enough to calculate only once for each row?

(If the information is needed, in my specific case I handle geo-coordinates using MySQL spatial functions ST_WITHIN, ST_GEOMFROMTEXT, etc.)

Comment: SELECT id, F(x) AS res
FROM test
WHERE res <= 1000;

Comment: @Aroniaina   the where don't should work with alias .......

Comment: None of the answers seem to answer the question.  Does MySQL reuse the computed column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - roughly speaking: `ORDER BY` and `HAVING` can use an alias of expressions in the `SELECT` list.  `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` can use an ordinal (as in `ORDER BY 1` which means to sort by the 1st column in the `SELECT`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that use a derived table is a good solution here :

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.res
FROM (
  SELECT id, F(x) as res
  FROM test
) AS t1
WHERE t1.res <= 1000;
```

Comment: That's a derived table, not a temporary table! Up-vote anyway.

Comment: Looks nice! I have no idea about the inner workings of MySQL. So I assume derived tables don't inherently come with their own performance issues.

Comment: @Christian - The `HAVING` solution is better.  See my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregates cannot be used in WHERE, but rather in HAVING. And you will need to add a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT id, F(x) as fx
FROM test
HAVING fx <= 1000;
```

If a condition refers to an aggregate function, put that condition in the HAVING clause. Otherwise, use the WHERE clause.

You can use HAVING but recommended you should use with GROUP BY.

SQL Standard says that WHERE restricts the result set before returning rows and HAVING restricts the result set after bringing all the rows. So WHERE is faster.

Comment: `F` is not an aggregate function that works over sets of tuples here. It's just a complex function of the value `x` for each row. For example, `F(x)` calculates the number of prime factors for `x`.

Comment: This solution (with `HAVING`) is likely to be more efficient than the other solutions with subqueries.  All evaluate F(x) exactly once per row, but the `HAVING` avoids creating an intermediate temp table with all the rows.